# In 2021, which MS Word to LaTeX conversion tool works best?

Tags: conversion, msword

The title says it all: In 2021, which MS Word to LaTeX conversion tool works best? By now, there is a myriad of options, both free and commercial, some involving first converting to `.odf` and then to LaTeX, others converting directly from `.docx` to LaTeX. One hardly knows where to get started. So does anyone have good experience about which one holds up best in 2021?

Important things to me are: Preferably, if it’s a simple, mainly text-based document, one should only have to readjust the preamble, not the main document. Bibliography support is also an important priority for me.

Comment: I still use the LibreOffice tool here: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/writer2latex-1 I don't have bibliographies.

Comment: For the first time using latex

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Word2TeX](https://www.chikrii.com/) many years ago (trial version) and it is very good also actually. See the link.  The proof that Word2TeX it is very good is that exists also in CTAN reference: https://ctan.org/pkg/word2tex. But it is not a free or gratis software.

I think that is the best.